# Android EditText ScrollingMovementMethod cause Null pointer Exception

Tags: android-edittext, android-scrollview, android-scroll, android-scrollbar

**In my Edittext scrollView in the scrollview LinearLayout, sometime the edittext throws exception, i dont know why this happen. any one have idea please help me .
Thanks on Advance**

This is my code:::

```
            edittext.setOnTouchListener(new ScrollView.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    try {
                        int action = event.getAction();
                            Log.e("action:",action+"");
                        switch (action) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                            // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                            float iniY = event.getRawY();
                            v.getParent().getParent().getParent()
                                    .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                            v.getParent().getParent()
                                    .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);

                            break;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("e", e.getMessage());
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

11-08 17:43:39.836: E/InputEventReceiver(10223): Exception dispatching input event.
    11-08 17:43:39.836: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10223): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
    11-08 17:43:39.851: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10223): java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: This is the stack trace, what is the exception ?

Comment: i got null pointer excepton

Comment: So add it to your post.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown DontVoteDown only for you uh???? if you are not intrest please dont vote down...

Comment: How do you know that? I didn't voted your down. You may have been voted down because your question is awful, and that is maybe why nobody have answered yet. Is too ugly too read, too few info, too bad formated(making your text entire bold will not bring attention to it). Learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) then you can say something.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown now ony i start learing thats y i said